# Table error when combining counts columns

Tags: r, rna-seq, bash

I have these files that I want to make table of (https://github.com/learnseq/RNAseqfiles01.git), the table that I want (since all the files have the same ID column),, I want merge the ID column with the count column from each file:

```
ID    File 1 count column     File 2 count column     File 3 count column   File 4 count column
```

I cleaned up the files from extra lines using:

```
grep -vE '^{' GSM2580324_counts.txt | grep -vE '^\\' | grep -v '^ *$' | sed '/^{/d'  | tr '\\' ' ' | sed '/}/d' | grep -vE '^__' > GSM2580324_counts04.txt
```

But when I try to make a table in R using this:

```
%R files = list.files(path=".", pattern="GSM")
%R file1 = read.table("GSM2580319_counts01.txt" , col.names=c("gene_id","GSM2580319_counts01.txt" ))
%R file2 = read.table("GSM2580320_counts02.txt" , col.names=c("gene_id","GSM2580320_counts02.txt" ))
%R file3 = read.table("GSM2580323_counts03.txt", col.names=c("gene_id","GSM2580323_counts03.txt" ))
%R file4 = read.table("GSM2580324_counts04.txt", col.names=c("gene_id","GSM2580324_counts04.txt"))
%R out.file = merge (file1, file2, by=c("gene_id"))
%R out.file2 <- merge(out.file, file3, by=c(\"gene_id\"))
%R out.file3 <- merge(out.file2, file4, by=c(\"gene_id\"))
%R outtable01 <- write.table(out.file, file = "out.file3",sep="\t", row.names = FALSE)
%R outtable01
```

I get this error:

```
RParsingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-179-2c471cf65113> in <module>
      7 get_ipython().run_line_magic('R', 'file4 = read.table("GSM2580324_counts04.txt", col.names=c("gene_id","GSM2580324_counts04.txt"))')
      8 get_ipython().run_line_magic('R', 'out.file = merge (file1, file2, by=c("gene_id"))')
----> 9 get_ipython().run_line_magic('R', 'out.file2 <- merge(out.file, file3, by=c(\\"gene_id\\"))')
     10 get_ipython().run_line_magic('R', 'out.file3 <- merge(out.file2, file4, by=c(\\"gene_id\\"))')
     11 get_ipython().run_line_magic('R', 'outtable01 <- write.table(out.file, file = "out.file3",sep="\\t", row.names = FALSE)')

/opt/applications/python/3.6.3/gnu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line, _stack_depth)
   2315                 kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
   2316             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2317                 result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2318             return result
   2319 

<decorator-gen-160> in R(self, line, cell, local_ns)

/opt/applications/python/3.6.3/gnu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    185     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    186     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 187         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    188 
    189         if callable(arg):

/opt/applications/python/3.6.3/gnu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/ipython/rmagic.py in R(self, line, cell, local_ns)
    729             if line_mode:
    730                 for line in code.split(';'):
--> 731                     text_result, result, visible = self.eval(line)
    732                     text_output += text_result
    733                 if text_result:

/opt/applications/python/3.6.3/gnu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/ipython/rmagic.py in eval(self, code)
    262             try:
    263                 # Need the newline in case the last line in code is a comment.
--> 264                 value, visible = ro.r("withVisible({%s\n})" % code)
    265             except (ri.embedded.RRuntimeError, ValueError) as exception:
    266                 # Otherwise next return seems to have copy of error.

/opt/applications/python/3.6.3/gnu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py in __call__(self, string)
    385 
    386     def __call__(self, string):
--> 387         p = rinterface.parse(string)
    388         res = self.eval(p)
    389         return conversion.rpy2py(res)

/opt/applications/python/3.6.3/gnu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface_lib/conversion.py in _(*args, **kwargs)
     38 def _cdata_res_to_rinterface(function):
     39     def _(*args, **kwargs):
---> 40         cdata = function(*args, **kwargs)
     41         # TODO: test cdata is of the expected CType
     42         return _cdata_to_rinterface(cdata)

/opt/applications/python/3.6.3/gnu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface.py in parse(text, num)
     44         raise TypeError('text must be a string.')
     45     robj = StrSexpVector([text])
---> 46     return _rinterface._parse(robj.__sexp__._cdata, num)
     47 
     48 

/opt/applications/python/3.6.3/gnu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface_lib/_rinterface_capi.py in _parse(cdata, num)
    556         if status[0] != openrlib.rlib.PARSE_OK:
    557             raise RParsingError('Parsing status not OK',
--> 558                                 PARSING_STATUS(status[0]))
    559     return res

RParsingError: Parsing status not OK
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your `grep`, why not just grep for what you want, *i.e.* `^ENSG.*`? (These last few lines that htseq-count outputs - which is the software that produces your files - are really important though. You should absolutely look into them to see if something strange is going on with one or more samples.)

Your error comes from the escaped quotes `\"` you use here:

```
out.file2 <- merge(out.file, file3, by=c(\"gene_id\"))
```

Before, you used:

```
out.file = merge (file1, file2, by=c("gene_id"))
```

which is the correct way to quote here. On a sidenote, you don't need `c()` if it's only a vector with one element. You can just write `by = "gene_id"`.

Here's a different way you could read the files:

```
files <- list.files(path=".", pattern="GSM")
count_files <- lapply(files, read.table, col.names = c("GeneID", "Count"))
count_matrix <- do.call(cbind, lapply(count_files, "[[", "Count"))
dimnames(count_matrix) <- list(count_files[[1]]["GeneID"], files)
```